# Cannot read property '0' of undefined vue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7

I have a problem working with arrays, So far am able to load data in view. My problem is now searching. If I add the array i get cannot read property '0' of undefined. But when this line is not img :src="'images2/'+product.images[0].filename" included am able to get values.

This is the code:

```html
<div v-for="product in Products.data" :key="product.id" class="p-2">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{product.title}}</h5>
      <div><img :src="'images2/'+product.images[0].filename" width="200" height="200"></div>
      <div class="itemv p-2"> Location:{{product.location}} </div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :href="'/products/'+product.id">View</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The property

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      id: '',
      Products: {
        images: [],
      },
    };
  },
};
```

and my search function

```js
created() {
  Fire.$on('searching', () => {
    let query = this.$parent.search;
    axios.get('/productsearch/?q=' + query)
    .then((data) => {
        this.Products = data.data
    })
    .catch(() => {

    })
  })
  this.loadProductData();
}
```

Comment: Try `v-for="product in Products"` instead of `v-for="product in Products.data"`

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh still i get the error TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: What is `Products`, an object or an array?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(data)` after the line `this.Products = data.data`, then see what it logs out.

Comment: After console I can get some data {…}
current_page: (...)
data: Array(2)
0:
created_at: (...)
description: "water available"
id: 12
location: "Base Stage Egp"
price: 4500
title: "Bungalo"
updated_at: (...)  but no image part. What there is that a product can have multiple images but in my case am just displaying one ie image[0] for every product all that i can achieve. When add the search , that is when i get the error

Comment: ***a product can have multiple images***, Does your data have any? 
The log result you give me, I can't grok it.

Comment: yes there is data

Comment: Does your data have `images`?

Comment: Before search there is image after search no image or data displayed in view.

Comment: That's why @user3736334

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh I have managed to clear the error using   {{ product.images && product.images.length > 0 ? product.images[0].filename : '' }} but this is only displaying the filename assist me to modify to  this     <div><img :src="'images2/'+product.images[0].filename" width="200" height="200"></div> to get the actual image

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forget to add "v-for" statement.

```
<div>
    <img v-for="{ id, images } of Products.data"
        :key="`product${id}`"
        :src="'images2/' + images[0].filename"
        width="200"
        height="200"
    >
</div>
```

The codes above will not render if `Products.images` is a empty `Array`.

It will render after the data is fetched.

Comment: Thanks, But now should it be inside the other v-for  <div v-for="product in Products.data" :key="product.id" class="p-2">

Comment: What is the structure of your data from server?

Comment: Am using laravel controller and this is the search method    public function search(){
        if ($search = \Request::get('q')) {
            $productrecord = Products::where(function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('title','LIKE',"%$search%");
            })->paginate(5);
        }else{
            $productrecord = Products::latest()->paginate(5);
        }
        return $productrecord;

    }

Comment: What you post is not what I mentioned. I mean if the data.data = { images: [] }? What is the data.data looks like? You can just console.log(data.data) and paste it at there.

Comment: id: 12
location: "Base Stage"
price: 4500
title: "Bungalo"
updated_at: "2021-01-30T04:26:44.000000Z"

Comment: Where is the images? If the images is not used now, you should edit your original post to show what you what to do.

Comment: That was after search before search i get current_page: (...)
data: Array(2)
0:
created_at: "2021-01-30T04:26:44.000000Z"
description: "water available"
data: Array(5)
0:
created_at: "2021-01-30T04:28:07.000000Z"
description: "water available"
id: 13
images: Array(3)
0: {…}
1: {…}
2: {…}
length: 3
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(3), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
location: "Base Stage "
price: 6700
title: "Bungalo"
updated_at: "2021-01-30T04:28:07.000000Z"

Comment: I have managed to clear the error using   {{ product.images && product.images.length > 0 ? product.images[0].filename : '' }} but this is only displaying the filename assist me to modifyto  this     <div><img :src="'images2/'+product.images[0].filename" width="200" height="200"></div> to get the actual image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228040/discussion-between-rex-hsu-and-user3736334).